# Where does the context object passed to onReceive() method in broadcast receiver come from?

Tags: android

I am very curious to know about the context object passed to onReceive() method in broadcast receiver.
Who passed it ? Does the context refers to the main Activity?

Comment: Hmm..The context of the broadcast generator?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link for your answers. It is clearly mentioned here
[broadcast receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers)

you can register broadcast receivers in two ways:

1. Manifest declared receivers where system package manager registers the receiver when the app is installed. Whenever an event for which your app has registered is generated, system delivers the event to your application.
2. Context based where receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. The context can be activity context which lives till the activity is alive or the application context which lives till the application is alive.